Ошибка при сборке проекта на next js14
При сборке проекта npm run build выводит ошибку:
Type error: Route "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
"authOptions" is not a valid Route export field.
Не понимаю как решить подскажите пожалуйста
import { getUser, saveUserCart, saveUserWishlist } from '@/lib/data';
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions, Session, SessionStrategy } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { z } from 'zod';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { User } from '@/types/types';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/sign-in',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials) {
          throw new Error('Учетные данные не были предоставлены');
        }

        // Извлекаем значения cart и wishlist из credentials с корректной типизацией
        const { cart, wishlist } = credentials as { cart: string; wishlist: string };

        const parsedCart = JSON.parse(cart);
        const parsedWishlist = JSON.parse(wishlist);

        const parsedCredentials = z
          .object({ login: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(8) })
          .safeParse(credentials);

        if (parsedCredentials.success) {
          const { login, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
          const user: User | undefined = await getUser(login);
          if (!user) throw new Error('Пользователь не найден');

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (passwordsMatch) {
            // Save user basket from database
            await saveUserCart(user.id, parsedCart);
            // Save user wishlist from database
            await saveUserWishlist(user.id, parsedWishlist);
            return user;
          }
        }
        console.log('Неверные данные');
        throw new Error('Неверные данные');
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt' as SessionStrategy,
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({
      token,
      user,
    }: {
      token: JWT;
      user: {
        id?: string | null | undefined;
        username?: string | null | undefined;
        email?: string | null | undefined;
        role?: string | null | undefined;
      };
    }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.username;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({
      session,
      token,
    }: {
      session: Session;
      user: {
        id?: string | null;
        username?: string | null;
        email?: string | null;
        role?: string | null;
      };
      token: JWT;
    }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
        session.user.name = token.name;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.role = token.role as string | null | undefined;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


а зачем тебе export const authOptions? Убери этот экспорт и заработает
